# How to get data in the column, which name is held in another column in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, lookup

1. I have a dataframe:

   ```
   import pandas as pd
   data = {'Alpha': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'Beta':[6, 7 ,8, 9, 10],
   'Delta': [11, 12, 13, 14, 15], 'Gamma': [16, 17, 18, 19, 20]}
   df = pd.DataFrame(data, index = ['2010', '2011', '2012', '2013', '2014'])
   df
   ```

[image]

2. It also has a column 'Select', holding other column names

   ```
   df['Select'] = ['Beta', 'Gamma', 'Gamma', 'Delta', 'Alpha']
   df
   ```

[image]

3. I need to add a column, say 'Choice', where data will be derived from the columns, names of which are held in 'Select' column, like below:

   ```
   df['Choice'] = [0,0,0,0,0]
   row = df['Select'].values
   for i in range(len(row)):
       df['Choice'][i] = df[row[i]][i]
   df
   ```

[image]

4. I'm doing it using a loop, but maybe there is some more elegant way? Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

we can use [DataFrame.lookup()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.lookup.html):

```
In [49]: df['new'] = df.lookup(df.index, df.Select)

In [50]: df
Out[50]:
      Alpha  Beta  Delta  Gamma Select  Choice  new
2010      1     6     11     16   Beta       6    6
2011      2     7     12     17  Gamma      17   17
2012      3     8     13     18  Gamma      18   18
2013      4     9     14     19  Delta      14   14
2014      5    10     15     20  Alpha       5    5
```